# What is the distribution assumption of the black scholes model

Tags: black-scholes, brownian-motion, normal-distribution

As per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model)
the Black Scholes assumption is:

(`random walk) The instantaneous log returns of the stock price is an infinitesimal random walk with drift; more precisely, it is a geometric Brownian motion`

But later on, under section, under [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model#Black.E2.80.93Scholes_in_practice)
to the right, there is picture and it says:

```
    The normality assumption of the Black–Scholes
 model does not capture extreme movements such as stock market crashes.
```

So does it assume a normal distribution or a GBM with drift?

Comment: The normality assumption is almost always referring to log returns, i.e. $\log (S_t/S_0)$, which is indeed normally distributed if $S_t$ is a GBM.

Comment: The article says that log returns are GBM, so maybe a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Black-Scholes framework, we assume the **log** returns are normally distributed. This is equal to saying the underlying is log-normally distributed. If you look at Geometric Brownian Motion on wikipedia, you'll see this:

```
The above solution  S_t  (for any value of t) is a **log-normally distributed** random variable
```

The wikipedia is correct.